# Filter using edges / vertices

Tags: graph, neo4j, gremlin

I try to filter nodes :

```
user = g.v(42);

g.idx('comparisons')[[id:Neo4jTokens.QUERY_HEADER + '*']]
.filter{
    if (it.out('COMPARED_VALUE1').in('VOTED').in('VOTES').next().equals(user))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}.count();
```

I don't really understand how pipes works, but I understand that the next() breaks something in the filter "loop".

I should get 2 results, but I get none.

Regards,

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I might need to amend my answer as I could require more specifics on what you are trying to achieve (as @Michael also requested), but if you think your problem is with `next()`, then consider the following:

```
user = g.v(42);

g.idx('comparisons')[[id:Neo4jTokens.QUERY_HEADER + '*']]
.filter{it.out('COMPARED_VALUE1').in('VOTED').in('VOTES').next().equals(user)}.count();
```

First, note above that your filter closure can immediately reduce to that (which will yield the same error, of course).  Given that filter closure you are assuming that a user vertex will come out of the pipeline when you `next()`.  That may not be the case.  As such, I would re-write the filter closure as:

```
user = g.v(42);

g.idx('comparisons')[[id:Neo4jTokens.QUERY_HEADER + '*']].filter{ 
    def p = it.out('COMPARED_VALUE1').in('VOTED').in('VOTES')
    p.hasNext() ? p.next().equals(user) : false
}.count();
```

That should likely solve your problem right there given the assumption that you only need to evaluate the first item in the pipeline `p` which is effectively what you were doing before.  I wonder if you couldn't simply use [except/retain pattern](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Except-Retain-Pattern) here to get your answer as it is a bit less convoluted:

```
user = g.v(42);

g.idx('comparisons')[[id:Neo4jTokens.QUERY_HEADER + '*']]
   .out('COMPARED_VALUE1').in('VOTED').in('VOTES').retain([user])
   .count();
```

Hopefully something here puts on you on the right track to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve?

Sorry my gremlin knowledge is close to zero these days.

In cypher it would probably look like this

```
START user=node(42), comp=node:comparisons("id:*")
MATCH comp-[:COMPARED_VALUE1]->()<-[:VOTED*2]-(user)
RETURN count(*)
```